# How to pass config setting in Django and keep module decoupled?

Tags: python, django, decoupling

In a Python Django project, I have a module with a class (let's say `SomeDataStore`) that abstracts file storage behaviour and requires a config setting with the correct path (different for development, prod, ...)

Currently, I've done it like this:

```
# settings.py
RELEVANT_PATH = os.environ.get("DJANGO_RELEVANT_PATH", "/some/default")
...

# datastore.py
from django.conf import settings
class SomeDataStore:
    def list_files(self):
        p = Path(settings.RELEVANT_PATH) 
        files = p.glob("*.csv")
        return files
    ...

# views.py
from datastatus import SomeDataStore
def show_files(request):
    files = SomeDataStore().get_files()
    ...
```

**Goal**: I'd like to decouple the `datastore.py` module completely from django, so that it can easily be used standalone. That would mean to get rid of the `django.conf.settings` usage in `datastore.py`

One obvious way to do it would be to provide the path as an init parameter to the `DataStore` class.

```
# datastore.py
class SomeDataStore:
    def __init__(self, path) -> None:
        self.path=path
    ...
```

However, I use this DataStore in many Django views, and that would require me to always specify the path when instantiating the class, e.g. like so

```
# views.py
from datastatus import SomeDataStore
def show_files(request):
    files = SomeDataStore(settings.RELEVANT_PATH).get_files()
    ...

def show_something_else(request):
    somethings = SomeDataStore(settings.RELEVANT_PATH).get_something_else()
    ...
```

I'd like to avoid the need in each instantiation to always specify the config setting for the path.

**Question**: Is there some clean way, pattern or approach to deal with this in Django? Or am I overlooking something obvious here?

Something I thought of is instantiating the `DataStore` in `settings.py`, but creating objects in `settings.py` seems bloating it. Or isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `my_settings.py` holding the PATH:

```py
# my_settings.py
import os
RELEVANT_PATH = os.environ.get("whatever", "/some/default")
```

and use like

```
# datastore.py
from my_settings import RELEVANT_PATH

class SomeDataStore:
    def list_files(self):
        p = Path(RELEVANT_PATH) 
        files = p.glob("*.csv")
        return files
    ...
```

In case you need this path whithin Django elsewhere, you could have this path as part of `settings.py` as well

```py
# settings.py
from my_settings import RELEVANT_PATH as my_relevant_path

RELEVANT_PATH = my_relevant_path

# usage in other django app files
from django.conf import settings
# use settings.RELEVANT_PATH as usual
```

This would provide for some decoupling and you can change the path at a single place `my_settings.py` and import the path outside django as well as use it inside django with the usual `django.conf.settings.xx` syntax.